# Override rails translations helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale, overriding, rails-i18n

I want `I18n.translate()` or `I18n.t()` to use a specific *locale*, but not *I18n.locale*.
I don't want to use `I18n.t(:my_key, locale: :my_locale)` every time, so it would be great if I could override the function itself.

I tried to put it in a new helper:

```
# my_helper.rb
module MyHelper
  def translate(key, options = {})
    options[:locale] = MY_LOCALE
    I18n.translate key, options
  end
  alias :t :translate
end
```

This works fine for "hard keys" like `t('word')`, but doesn't find the right path for "dynamic keys" like `t('.title')`, which should use the path of my partial, i.e. `de.users.form.title`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i think you are missing the `I18n.with_locale` method

Comment: Thank you for comment. `I18n.with_locale(MY_LOCALE) {}` would be the same thing as `I18n.t(:key, locale: MY_LOCALE)`. I hoped for a solution with the standard `I18n.t()` function and a centralized definition of the locale that I want to use.

Comment: Can't you just set the locale from a param, from a domain, or something similar, like discussed here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale ? That way, you would set the locale per request and then you could use `I18n.t` just like normal, but using the locale set for the request instead of the default locale.

Comment: Hey Frost, thanks for your answer. I want to use a specific I18n.locale for the database updates, but another language for the user interface. Example: A German user **with a German UI** should edit French contents **with french slugs**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would seem that there is some confusion between the functionalities of:

- [`I18n.translate`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.rb#L144), from the I18n gem and
- [`ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper#translate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L37), from Rails

`I18n.translate` does not perform the "lazy lookups" (ie scoping the lookup key to the current partial if it begins with a dot) that you are expecting.  That is a feature of `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper#translate`, along with [some others](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate).

Your method is overriding `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper#translate`, without a call to `super` to get lazy loading.  So, if you want to persist on overriding the method, I think you may want:

```
# my_helper.rb
module MyHelper
  def translate(key, options = {})
    # If you don't want to ignore options[:locale] if it's passed in,
    # change to options[:locale] ||= MY_LOCALE
    options[:locale] = MY_LOCALE 
    super(key, options)
  end
  alias :t :translate
end
```

Personally though, I'd rather use `t(:my_key, locale: :my_locale)` every time in my views without the override, or at most have a separate helper method that wraps around a call to `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper#translate` with the extra business logic of forcing a specific locale.

Answer (score 1):

You can try next:

config/initializers/i18n.rb

```
module I18n
  def german(*args)
    options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop.dup : {}
    args << options.merge(locale: :de)
    translate(*args)
  end
  module_function :german
end
```

And if you need to define several module functions, it'll be easier to use next construction instead of `module_function` each time:

```
module I18n
  extend(Module.new do
    def german
      ...
    end

    def english
      ...
    end

    def japaneese
      ...
    end
  end)
end
```